# How to remove an app from 'open with' list by not resetting launch services

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

My case is my app's function is to give user some remote apps to use, when user first entered my app, there will call LSRegisterURL and other method to update launch services, so that 'open with' list will contains these remote apps.

But when user delete my app, the registered remote app is still in the 'open with' list, how can I get rid of that thing? I googled some methods, like using some native commands to reset launch services, but that needs to restart Mac, can we have a warm way to do this job?

Comment: Resetting launch services database does not require a restart

Comment: @vadian can reset be done via code? We can't let user manually reset that database

Comment: The system CLI `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister` can do this called via `NSTask`